# Laravel optional where() query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I wonder if there is something like a optional where query. Eg:

Select * from table where X must be = 2 and Y must be equal to 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try as:

```
$userId = $request->input('userId');
->where('X', 2)
->where(function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('Y', $userId)
        ->orWhere('Y', 1)
})
```

Comment: How do I pass a dynamic value to that? Eg ``$q->where('Y', $userId)``

Comment: thanks that worked, I will accept in 7 min once it lets me

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

You can get objects back through the model too:

```
$collection = Mymodel::where('x', 2)->where('y', 0)->orWhere('y', 1)->get();
```

Or like Amit shows above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orWhere()` for simple cases, but in your case you should use a function to return the where clause for y like:

```
$result = $field->letters()->where('x', 2)->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where('y', 0)->orWhere('y', 1);
})->get();
```

Note: replace *letters* with your object model.